# Would $watch be of any use here?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm Using an angularjs directive template to render a single computed value (a sum total) from a model passed in.

If I render the value normally using the template there is no problem.
The value rendered is simply the sum of a bunch of row object values passed into the directive/template as so:

```
ngApp.directive('subtotal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { 
            icRows: '='
        },
        template: '<div><strong>Sub Total:</strong> {{subTotal()}}</div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $scope.subTotal = function() {
                var t = 0;
                for(var i=0; i<$scope.icRows.length; i++ ) {
                    t += $scope.icRows[i].price;
                }
                return t;
            }
        }
    };
});


<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <input ng-model="row.name" /> | <input ng-model="row.price" />
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <subtotal ic-rows="rows"></subtotal>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine.
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jralston/p8FLV/

My issue is where the 'subTotal' variable is actually the result of an AJAX call. This ajax call needs to be invoked when a change to the 'rows' variable occurs. To do this I've adjusted the template in the directive to:

```
<div><strong>Sub Total:</strong> {{subTotalInvoker()}} {{subTotal}}</div>
```

Now in the directive, the function $scope.subTotalInvoker() invokes the ajax call. The callback from that sets the value of 'subTotal'

Again, this works perfectly fine.

Demo here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jralston/wpYjL/

However, it seems like a completely wrong way of doing it.

I tried adding a $watch to $scope.icRows but it didn't work. Perhaps I was doing something wrong.

Any pointers and/or corrections on how best to do this are very welcome.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1 - Using $watchCollection

You can use $watchCollection. $watchCollection will call its watch handler when the entire array is replaced on scope (i.e. $scope.icRows = []), when an item is added or removed from icRows, or one of items is replaced.

```
ngApp.directive('subtotal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { 
            icRows: '='
        },
        template: '<div><strong>Sub Total:</strong> {{subTotal}}</div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $scope.subTotal = 0;
            $scope.$watchCollection('icRows', function(newVal) {
                var t = 0;
                for(var i=0; i<newVal.length; i++ ) {
                    t += newVal[i].price;
                }
                $scope.subTotal = t;
            }

        }
    };
});
```

### Solution 2 - Using a Deep $watch

But I suspect this is not suitable since '.price' may change, and $watchCollection does not check an item's properties for changes.

If you need a deep watch (searches for changes to properties and sub-properties as well), then use $watch and pass true as the second argument:

```
$scope.$watch('icRows', function(newVal) {
     ...
}, true);
```

$watch(true) has nuances that you need to be aware of though. I'm not sure if this has changed in recent updates to Angular, but back when I was using it, I found that $watch(true) does not check for adds/deletes from the array, or even if the array is replaced entirely. It does do a deep watch though.

### Filters - an Alternative Approach

A filter will work similar to $watchCollection. The drawback is that the filter does not update when the item's .price property changes.

```
ngApp.filter('subtotal', function() {
    return function(input) { 
         var t = 0; 
         for (var i= 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
             t += parseFloat(input[i].price);
         }
         return t;
    }
});
```

Then in your HTML, you can apply your filter to your array that you have on scope:

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <input ng-model="row.name" /> | <input ng-model="row.price" />
        </div>
        <hr/>
        {{ rows | subtotal | currency }}
    </div>
</div>
```

If this meets your requirements, there is no need for a custom directive, and you can further format the result as currency using the [currency filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).

Comment: Thanks Pixelbits. The $watchCollection part of your answer works ok but as you suggested, it doesn't work for the example at hand where a value within row is updated (i.e. typing in the price field in the jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/jralston/edkhf/ The second part using the filter unfortunatly doesn't seem to be applicable because it doesn't account for the ajax callback. Thanks though, very informative answer.

Comment: The filter should work to produce the result you need. How are you calling ajax? Are you are using $http service?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the middle part of your answer (did you edit?) anyway, spot-on with the $watch('icRows,function(newVal){},true). that worked perfectly. Demo here: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/jralston/Vr63f/[/link] Thanks very much

Comment: Re ajax. It's simulated in the second jsFiddle in the question using the setTimeout function. It's this that is the source of the question because two things are happening. 1. A change to the icRows array is invoking an event 2. It is the call back from this ajax that is updating the variable. I'm not using $http service and not in a position to do so. Thanks a mil.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a directive or a filter.  Just put a `subTotal()` function in your controller:

```
$scope.subTotal = function(rows){
    var t = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++ ) {
        t += rows[i].price;
    }
    return t;
}
```

And bind that function in your HTML:

```
<div><strong>Sub Total:</strong> {{subTotal(rows)}}</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/JaW5w/2/)

Comment: +1 for observing that a filter or directive isn't needed, this answer doesn't account for the ajax callback though. I.e. a change to the icRows collection triggers an ajax call for which the callback will update the variable at hand.